# Get posts from each category once inside a section tag with category as id

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

```
$args = array(
    'type'                     => 'post',
    'child_of'                 => 0,
    'parent'                   => '',
    'orderby'                  => 'name',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 1,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'exclude'                  => '',
    'include'                  => '',
    'number'                   => '',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
    'pad_counts'               => false
 );
$categories = get_categories($args);
// print_r($categories);

foreach ($categories as $cat) { ?>
    <section id="<?php echo $cat->slug ?>-section"><?php
    $args2 = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'category_name' => $cat->slug
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args2 );
        if($query->have_posts()) :
            while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>
                <h2 class="<?php echo $cat->slug ?>-heading">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_title() ?></a>
                </h2>
                <div class="post-date">
                    <?php the_time('d. m. Y') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="post-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div><?php
            endwhile;
    endif;
  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</section> <?php
}
```

gets me all posts from each category inside a `section` tag with post category as `id`.

However this also gets me the same result without using `new Wp_Query`.

```
$args = array(
        'type'                     => 'post',
        'child_of'                 => 0,
        'parent'                   => '',
        'orderby'                  => 'name',
        'order'                    => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'               => 1,
        'hierarchical'             => 1,
        'exclude'                  => '',
        'include'                  => '',
        'number'                   => '',
        'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
        'pad_counts'               => false
     );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    // print_r($categories);
    foreach ($categories as $cat) { ?>
        <section id="<?php echo $cat->slug ?>-section">
            <?php
            // Get posts from each category
            $args2= array("orderby"=>'name', "category" => $cat->cat_ID);
            $posts_in_category = get_posts($args2);
            foreach( $posts_in_category as $current_post ) { ?>
                <h2 class="<?php echo $cat->slug ?>-heading">
                    <a href="<?php echo $current_post->guid; ?>"><?php echo $current_post->post_title; ?></a>
                </h2>
                <div class="post-date">
                    <?php the_time('d. m. Y') ?>
                    <?php echo $current_post->post_date; ?>
                    <!-- <?php // echo $current_post->the_time('d. m. Y') ?> -->
                </div>
                <div class="post-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php echo $current_post->post_content; ?>
                </div> <?php
            }
            ?>
        </section> <?php
    }
```

In the second approach I cannot set the date as I want to with `echo $current_post->the_time('d. m. Y')` but would have to format `post_date` what is [kind of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175498/how-do-i-format-the-post-date-in-wordpress) [tricky](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37163/proper-formatting-of-post-date-for-wp-insert-post).

Not being familiar with not working with `new WP_Query` but with `$args2= array("orderby"=>'name', "category" => $cat->cat_ID);` and using `get_posts` does not feel right to me.

Both approaches query the database for each category, one with `new WP_Query` and the other with `get_posts`.

What is the best practise and performant way to query the database so that all posts inside each category are shown inside a `section` tag with category as `id`?

Comment: Here is a nice question and answers https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts